# Conditional expectation and independence

Tags: independence, conditional-expectation

Consider 3 random variables $X$, $Y$, $Z$. Suppose:

1. $E(X)=0$
2. $E(X|Y) =0$
3. $Z\perp Y $

Does this imply $E(X|Y,Z) = E(X|Z)$?

Comment: No it does not.  What have you tried?

Comment: I've tried to show that $p(X|Y,Z) = p(X|Z)$ given the assumptions, and playing with the conditional probability/Bayes rule. Could not make it work, but my inability to prove it does not imply it does not hold :)

Comment: Though failure to prove may suggest looking for a counter-example could be worthwhile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have

```
 X  Y  Z  prob

 0  0  0   1/4
 0  0  1   1/4
+1  1  0   1/4
-1  1  1   1/4
```

then the conditions are satisfied

while $E[X \mid Y=0, Z=0] = 0$ while $E[X \mid Z=0]=\frac12$

Comment: Beautifully simple. Thanks